# Trouble with resources from appcompat-v7:22.2.0 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

We've got a base project from University to build upon. So I installed `Android Studio`, installed and updated the Android SDK (API 22) and the all the extras and opened the project, which has the `appcompat-v7` library included under External Libraries.
When I'm trying to build the app I get the following error messages:

```
C:\PRIVAT\Universität Regensburg\SS-2015\Anwendungsprogrammierung-mit-Android\Studienleistungen\02-Studienleistung\FoodieAppStarterProject\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.2.0\res\layout\notification_media_cancel_action.xml
Error:(26, 18) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha').
C:\PRIVAT\Universität Regensburg\SS-2015\Anwendungsprogrammierung-mit-Android\Studienleistungen\02-Studienleistung\FoodieAppStarterProject\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.2.0\res\drawable\abc_btn_check_material.xml
Error:(18, 58) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015').
Error:(19, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000').
```

... and so on. I get lots and lots of these. And I have no idea why. Everything seems to be correct.

Can anyone help based on this.

Comment: What's the `compileSdkVersion` defined in the `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I have the same problem with Android studio. However interestingly command line build is perfectly fine: gradle clean assembleDebug

Comment: For me, strangely, the path to the file was too long. I copied my entire project directory to desktop(to reduce the length of path string and it worked correctly.

Comment: can you show us the `build.gradle` file ?

Answer (score 11):

As you can see here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23.2.0/changes/android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.html

The drawable reference had been updated, so you need to update the variable name:

```
abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha      -> abc_ic_clear_material
abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015 -> abc_btn_checkbox_checked_mtrl
abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000 -> abc_btn_checkbox_unchecked_mtrl
abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha -> abc_ic_ab_back_material
```

---

But, you should notice, if you use these resources on devices with API level <= 19. That will trigger an exception `Resource Not Found`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I updated to use the latest plugin name and bumped up my compile sdk version (may not be related).

Old plugin name:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

Use the new plugin name:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  In my case, the project path was too long.  I moved the project folder to make the path shorter and all was OK.  Your path looks pretty long in the error.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using API 22 you don't need AppCompat and can remove it. I found a blog post that explains the details here and it worked for me: https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/removing-support-library-in-android-studio

Here is what it says (I have added some additional help):

Open build.gradle from your project. Locate the dependencies section.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Remove the line for the compatibility library. After that the section should look like this.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Save and close.

By default the app uses a theme that is available from the support library. This is not available from the core API. So we need to fix that. Open `res/values/styles.xml`. The style tag will look something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Change the parent to a theme that is available from the core SDK. For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Rename properties in the activity xml files such as `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`.

Extent your activity classes from `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` and `AppCompatActivity`. You'll have to press Alt+Enter on `Activity` once you have made the changes to add import android.app.Activity at the top of the file. See the example below:

Change:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

to:

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And the same for any other activities that extends `ActionBarActivity` and `AppCompatActivity`

Finally, perform a `Build | Clean Project` and a `Build | Rebuild Project` to sort out the current build errors.

Comment: Should he use a Holo theme in the 2015? completely wrong. Also without appcompat, you can't use the design support library,